# ArrayList initialization through List.of()

Tags: java, arraylist

From Core Java for the Impatient:

> ... there is no initializer syntax for array lists. The best you can
>   do is construct an array list like this:

```
ArrayList<String> friends =  new ArrayList<>(List.of("Peter", "Paul"));
```

But when I'm try compiling this code getting error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
                ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Peter", "Paul"));
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable List
```

My imports are:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Thanks

Comment: try `Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Peter", "Paul"})`

Comment: List.of is available starting from java 9

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `Arrays.asList("Peter", "Paul")` is sufficient

Comment: @azro the result produced by `Arrays.asList()` is immutable - OP clearly wants it to be mutable

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek I never said to use it ;) I just answer to Xtreme's comment ;)

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek The result of `Arrays.asList` is **not** immutable, it is just fixed length, but you can modify the values at existing indexes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// ...
ArrayList<String> friends =  new ArrayList<>(List.of("Peter", "Paul"));
```

Is perfectly fine assuming you're running at least Java 9.

---

Prior to Java 9, you need to go for `Arrays.asList()` instead of `List.of()`:

```
ArrayList<String> friends =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Peter", "Paul"));
```

Comment: As an aside, I found eventually using stream more standardized with similar (but not same) syntax for Double, String etc: `List<Double> doublesList = Arrays.stream(doubles).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)); List<String> stringsList = Arrays.stream(strings).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`